# Where is package.resolved stored?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, swift-package

## Problem

- I am using Swift Package in my project
- I can't find `package.resolved` in the following path:
  `[appName].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/` (even tried showing the hidden files)

## My findings:

- Following path exists but is empty:
  `[appName].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm` doesn't contain .resolved  file
- `[appName].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/configuration` is empty

## Environment

- macOS 13.0.1 (22A400)
- Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b)

## Background

I wanted to check if `package.resolved` was checked it into git, but now I don't know where to find it.

## Questions:

- Where can I find Package.resolved file?
- Or has this been changed to a different filename?

Comment: You could always grep -r at in the root directory for .resolved

Comment: It is not present even when greping, I would appreciate if you don't blindly close issues without confirming / understanding the underlying issue

Comment: I simply suggested searching for it using grep, there are people who don't know how to do that, not judging.  No closing or voting from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

For some reason the `Package.resolved` file was missing, not sure why.

## Workaround / Solution

- Remove and add the Swift Package to the project, this caused the `Package.resolved` to be created

Answer (score 0):

Location of `Package.resolved` is explained in the Swift Package Manager documentation on [Package Dependency](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html):

> The Swift Package Manager performs a process called dependency
> resolution to figure out the exact version of the package dependencies
> that an app or other Swift package can use. The Package.resolved file
> records the results of the dependency resolution and lives in the
> top-level directory of a Swift package. If you add the Swift package
> as a package dependency to an app for an Apple platform, you can find
> the Package.resolved file inside your .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace.

Sure enough, right clicking on the `.xcdoeproj` or `.xcworkspace` file, selecting "Show Package Contents", then exploring shows the `Package.resolved` file located in:

```
MyApp.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved
```

[image]

A non-existent `Package.resolved` may be because Xcode has yet to complete the dependency resolution process for the project or workspace.